# Change the id of a theme element

Tags: plone, xslt, diazo

Using Diazo, I have an id clash between the theme and the content and some JS which depends on the content id.  How can I change the elements id attribute in the theme from one value to another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to change a value in the theme is to open it in your editor and edit the html ;) If you're after changing the id in the content to match markup in the theme then you can use a replace content rule, see: http://diazo.org/advanced.html#modifying-the-content-on-the-fly

(The replace content rule basically replaces xsl:template's in Diazo. The latter still work, but you should normally use the replace content now.)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```xml
<replace css:theme="{theme-selector}" css:content="{content-selector}" />
<xsl:template match="{theme-selector}">
  <xsl:attribute name="{attr-name}">
    <xsl:value-of select="{attr-value}" />
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

More info:

- [How to transform block of content from plone being inserted into diazo theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5749561/how-to-transform-block-of-content-from-plone-being-inserted-into-diazo-theme)
- [XSLT: How to change an attribute value during <xsl:copy>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/615875/xslt-how-to-change-an-attribute-value-during-xslcopy)
- http://diazo.org/advanced.html#modifying-the-content-on-the-fly

Comment: This isn't working for me.  Did you notice that this element is in the theme?  I never replace it with something from the content.

Comment: when you say "*id clash clash between the theme and the content*" one thinks that you are replacing/copying something from the content to the theme. Anyway, I would try to skip the first line, using the rest. If it doesn't work either, I hope that  you can find more clues on the linked doc. Good luck